# How to build Stack Yesod?

Tags: haskell, cabal, yesod, haskell-stack

I've been trying to use stack to start a yesod-simple project, but nothing I do will build this project. I've looked into other similar stackoverflow questions but couldn't get this to work. Can some one help me figure out what I need to do to get started?

### Error

```
> stack build

Populated index cache.
yesod-persistent-1.4.0.6: configure
yesod-persistent-1.4.0.6: build
yesod-persistent-1.4.0.6: copy/register
yesod-form-1.4.9: configure
yesod-form-1.4.9: build
yesod-form-1.4.9: copy/register
yesod-auth-1.4.15: configure
yesod-auth-1.4.15: build
Progress: 3/6
--  While building package yesod-auth-1.4.15 using:
  /Users/scottyluciano/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-osx/setup-Simple-Cabal-1.22.5.0-ghc-7.10.3 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.22.5.0 build --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
Logs have been written to: /Users/scottyluciano/Documents/tutorials/practice/.stack-work/logs/yesod-auth-1.4.15.log

Configuring yesod-auth-1.4.15...
Building yesod-auth-1.4.15...
Preprocessing library yesod-auth-1.4.15...
[ 1 of 12] Compiling Yesod.PasswordStore ( Yesod/PasswordStore.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/Yesod/PasswordStore.o )

/private/var/folders/kl/yp2gqzf116131b5gvs9pzttw0000gn/T/stack64861/yesod-auth-1.4.15/Yesod/PasswordStore.hs:166:31: Warning:
    Defaulting the following constraint(s) to type ‘Integer’
      (Integral b0)
        arising from a use of ‘^’ at Yesod/PasswordStore.hs:166:31
      (Num b0)
        arising from the literal ‘32’ at Yesod/PasswordStore.hs:166:32-33
    In the first argument of ‘(-)’, namely ‘2 ^ 32’
    In the first argument of ‘(*)’, namely ‘(2 ^ 32 - 1)’
    In the second argument of ‘(>)’, namely ‘(2 ^ 32 - 1) * hLen’

/private/var/folders/kl/yp2gqzf116131b5gvs9pzttw0000gn/T/stack64861/yesod-auth-1.4.15/Yesod/PasswordStore.hs:419:1: Warning:
    Defined but not used: ‘toStrict’

/private/var/folders/kl/yp2gqzf116131b5gvs9pzttw0000gn/T/stack64861/yesod-auth-1.4.15/Yesod/PasswordStore.hs:422:1: Warning:
    Defined but not used: ‘fromStrict’
[ 2 of 12] Compiling Yesod.Auth.Message ( Yesod/Auth/Message.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/Yesod/Auth/Message.o )

/private/var/folders/kl/yp2gqzf116131b5gvs9pzttw0000gn/T/stack64861/yesod-auth-1.4.15/Yesod/Auth/Message.hs:24:1: Warning:
    The import of ‘mappend’ from module ‘Data.Monoid’ is redundant

/private/var/folders/kl/yp2gqzf116131b5gvs9pzttw0000gn/T/stack64861/yesod-auth-1.4.15/Yesod/Auth/Message.hs:460:1: Warning:
    Pattern match(es) are overlapped
    In an equation for ‘finnishMessage’: finnishMessage Password = ...

/private/var/folders/kl/yp2gqzf116131b5gvs9pzttw0000gn/T/stack64861/yesod-auth-1.4.15/Yesod/Auth/Message.hs:460:1: Warning:
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for ‘finnishMessage’:
        Patterns not matched: CurrentPassword
[ 3 of 12] Compiling Yesod.Auth.Routes ( Yesod/Auth/Routes.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/Yesod/Auth/Routes.o )
[ 4 of 12] Compiling Yesod.Auth       ( Yesod/Auth.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/Yesod/Auth.o )
ghc: panic! (the 'impossible' happened)
  (GHC version 7.10.3 for x86_64-apple-darwin):
    Loading temp shared object failed: dlopen(/var/folders/kl/yp2gqzf116131b5gvs9pzttw0000gn/T/ghc65133_0/libghc_21.dylib, 5): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /var/folders/kl/yp2gqzf116131b5gvs9pzttw0000gn/T/ghc65133_0/libghc_21.dylib: malformed mach-o: load commands size (36784) > 32768

Please report this as a GHC bug:  http://www.haskell.org/ghc/reportabug
```

Comment: Can you try one of this workaround: https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/faq/#why-is-dyld_library_path-ignored ?

Comment: Are you on macOS Sierra? In that case you need to use GHC 8.2, which fixes the panic issue. You should more or less be able to set your stack LTS to the just arrived 8.0, and upgrade with no to minor changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GHC 8.0.2 fixes the panic issue](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2577#issuecomment-256135836). By changing LTS to 8.0, the upgrade resolves all issues.