# Haskell tool stack upgrade not working

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm trying to upgrade `stack` on my MacBook from v1.2.0 to the latest v1.4.0. When I try `stack upgrade` it ends with the following error. How can I get this to work?

```
stack-1.4.0: build
Preprocessing library stack-1.4.0...
[  1 of 124] Compiling Text.PrettyPrint.Leijen.Extended ( src/Text/PrettyPrint/Leijen/Extended.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/Text/PrettyPrint/Leijen/Extended.o )
[  2 of 124] Compiling Hackage.Security.Client.Repository.HttpLib.HttpClient ( src/Hackage/Security/Client/Repository/HttpLib/HttpClient.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/Hackage/Security/Client/Repository/HttpLib/HttpClient.o )
[  3 of 124] Compiling Stack.Options.ScriptParser ( src/Stack/Options/ScriptParser.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/Stack/Options/ScriptParser.o )
[  4 of 124] Compiling Stack.Ghci.Script ( src/Stack/Ghci/Script.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/Stack/Ghci/Script.o )
[  5 of 124] Compiling Stack.FileWatch  ( src/Stack/FileWatch.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/Stack/FileWatch.o )
[  6 of 124] Compiling System.Process.PagerEditor ( src/System/Process/PagerEditor.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/System/Process/PagerEditor.o )
[  7 of 124] Compiling System.Process.Log ( src/System/Process/Log.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/System/Process/Log.o )
[  8 of 124] Compiling Paths_stack      ( .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/autogen/Paths_stack.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/Paths_stack.o )
[  9 of 124] Compiling Path.Find        ( src/Path/Find.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/Path/Find.o )
[ 10 of 124] Compiling Path.Extra       ( src/Path/Extra.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/Path/Extra.o )
[ 11 of 124] Compiling System.Process.Read ( src/System/Process/Read.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/System/Process/Read.o )
ghc: panic! (the 'impossible' happened)
  (GHC version 7.10.3 for x86_64-apple-darwin):
        Loading temp shared object failed: dlopen(/var/folders/x3/y7dgvx7j0lx1clp5vsrlt3p40000gn/T/ghc61111_0/libghc_68.dylib, 5): no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /var/folders/x3/y7dgvx7j0lx1clp5vsrlt3p40000gn/T/ghc61111_0/libghc_68.dylib: malformed mach-o: load commands size (49368) > 32768

Please report this as a GHC bug:  http://www.haskell.org/ghc/reportabug

Completed 26 action(s).

--  While building package stack-1.4.0 using:
      /private/var/folders/x3/y7dgvx7j0lx1clp5vsrlt3p40000gn/T/stack-upgrade57904/stack-1.4.0/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.22.5.0/setup/setup --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.22.5.0 build lib:stack exe:stack --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

**Update**: @Sibi suggested I try `stack upgrade --binary-only`:

```
$ stack upgrade --binary-only
Invalid option `--binary-only'

Usage: stack upgrade [--git] [--git-repo ARG] [--help]
  Upgrade to the latest stack (experimental)
```

Comment: Try doing: `stack upgrade --binary-only`

Comment: This sounds like the Sierra upgrade issue. Sibi's suggestion should deal with it. For details, cf. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41531416/2751851), as well as Stack issue [#2577](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2577) and its duplicate [#2841](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2841). (N.B.: I don't use OS X, and only know the issue secondhand.)

Comment: @Sibi - `--binary-only` didn't work for me unfortunately, doesn't seem to be a recognized option. I posted the result in the question as it didn't format nicely in this comment.